# Create and update state dynamically via TextFields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Not sure if title says what I want to achieve, if not, please correct me. So Basically I want to make component which will create the form based on json file. Let's say someone click in navbar "light" I wish to create form which will fit to the fields which belongs to "light" in json file. I already achieved it with my code, the solution can save lots of work later when I add more modules as they will be created dynamically based on json, instead of separate component for each form. But I would like to ask you guys for advice as I don't know how to achieve managing state here. I mean after filling a form I want to send it via send button. The thing is that first I gotta collect data somewhere, in state. But If i create form based on json, then state will each time has different fields. Is there any way to create and update state while filling the TextFields without define it first? my code :

```
import React from 'react'
import { Typography, FormControl, TextField, FormControlLabel, Button} from "@material-ui/core";
import fakeModule from "./fakeModule"
import { connect } from "react-redux";


function SetModule(props) {
    return(
        <div>
        {props.settedModule 
        ? Object.entries(fakeModule).map(([key, val], i) => {
            if (props.settedModule == key) {
                console.log(val)
                return (
                <FormControl key={i}>
                    <Typography>{props.moduleConfig}</Typography>
                    {Object.entries(val).map(([name, value], index) => {
                        return (
                        <FormControlLabel
                            key={index}
                            control={
                                <TextField
                                    label={value}
                                    margin="normal" />
                            }
                            label={name} />
                        )
                    })}
                </FormControl>
                )
            }
        })
        : <div>Set Module first</div>}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        settedModule: state.settedModule
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SetModule)
```

Here is example of my JSON object, latter I'm gonna add new modules with their parameters like battery etc etc:

```
const moduleData = {
  light: {
      intensity: "20",
      threshold_on: "7",
      threshold_off: "19",
      mode: "ON",
      measurement_period: "1",
      measurement_state: "1",
      filter: "3",
      range: "0"
  },
  sleep: {
    SLEEP_TIME: 120,
    MODULE_PRIORITY: 999
  }
};

export default moduleData
```

Comment: You literally just need to take the settedModule prop and convert it into a state-object with a structure that you can use to create controlled-inputs for your component mark-up. Would you like to take a stab at that? I guess for starters, show us what your json object looks like.

Comment: hi @ChristopherNgo thanks for reply, I updated my question with my JSON object settedModule prop is just a string like this: ```<MenuItem onClick={e => handleCloseAndSwitch(e, "light")} component={Link} to="/module" >``` where I look for string in this case 'light' with the one in JSON object to use it to create form

Answer (score 0):

I think [React-jsonschema](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/) can be a good solution for you

Doc: [React-jsonschema doc](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

The code below, allows to generate a simple form from a json using jsonschema module. Your json must be structured by following the examples on [link](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/)

```
import React from 'react';
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";

const data={
    title: "A single-field form",
    type: "string"
  }

class TestJsonschema extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.Submission=this.Submission.bind(this);
    }
    Submission(value){
        console.log(value.formData) 
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Form schema={data} uiSchema={{}} onSubmit={this.Submission}>

            </Form>              
        )
    }
}

export default TestJsonschema
```

Comment: Whilst we love links to external sources, leaving link-only answers is discourages as the answer will become useless when the link expires. Please update your answer to include more detail :)

Comment: seems interesting but so far I keep failing in attempts to implement it to my current code, but keep trying tho